# Convert ARGB to RGB without losing information

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, colors

i try to convert a argb value to a rgb-value without losing the information it got from his background. 
so for example: the background is black, the argb is (150,255,0,0) and as the result i wan't to have a kind of brown.

is there any chance to deal with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may calculate

```
foreground * alpha + background * (1-alpha)
```

as your new color for channels red, green and blue. Note that I used an `alpha` scaled to `0` to `1` in the expression.

Comment: you may take my example to explain it? can't imagine how i should get 3 values out of this equation. thanks

Comment: Does this apply the same way to "premultiplied" as well as "straight" formats? (PixelFormat.Alpha vs PixelFormat.PAlpha in C#). My guess is that Premultiplied means that we should leave the first multiplication with alpha out? But that would not make much sense since each channel would need more than one byte (or short) to hold the same data... or do the premultiplied formats just do that?

Answer (score 10):

```
    public static Color RemoveAlpha(Color foreground, Color background)
    {
        if (foreground.A == 255)
            return foreground;

        var alpha = foreground.A / 255.0;
        var diff = 1.0 - alpha;
        return Color.FromArgb(255,
            (byte)(foreground.R * alpha + background.R * diff),
            (byte)(foreground.G * alpha + background.G * diff),
            (byte)(foreground.B * alpha + background.B * diff));
    }
```

from http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Shared/Utilities/ColorUtility.cs